# Python dictionary (/w values being lists of various length) to Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary like this. The values are lists of different length.

```
{'New England': ['connecticut',
  'maine',
  'massachusetts',
  'new hampshire',
  'rhode island',
  'vermont'],
 'Mideast': ['delaware',
  'district of columbia',
  'maryland',
  'new jersey',
  'new york',
  'pennsylvania'],
 'Great Lakes': ['illinois', 'indiana', 'michigan', 'ohio', 'wisconsin'],
 'Plains': ['iowa',
  'kansas',
  'minnesota',
  'missouri',
  'nebraska',
  'north dakota',
  'south dakota'],
 'Southeast': ['alabama',
  'arkansas',
  'florida',
  'georgia',
  'kentucky',
  'louisiana',
  'mississippi',
  'north carolina',
  'south carolina',
  'tennessee',
  'virginia',
  'west virginia'],
 'Southwest': ['arizona', 'new mexico', 'oklahoma', 'texas'],
 'Rocky Mountain': ['colorado', 'idaho', 'montana', 'utah', 'wyoming'],
 'Far West': ['alaska',
  'california',
  'hawaii',
  'nevada',
  'oregon',
  'washington']}
```

I want to make it into a Pandas dataframe with 2 columns, like the one below

```
+-------------+--------------+
|region       | state        |
+-------------|--------------+
|New England  | connecticut  |
+-------------|--------------+
|New England  | maine        |
+-------------|--------------+
|New England  | massachusetts|
+-------------|--------------+
|New England  | new hampshire|
+-------------|--------------+
| Mideast     | new york     |
+-------------|--------------+
| Mideast     | new jersey   |
+-------------|--------------+
```

How can I achieve it?

I have a column of US states and I want to classify them into regions so I need a data frame to merge.

BIG THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` with flatten values of lists in keys for list of tuples passed to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, x) for k, v in d.items() for x in v],
                  columns=['region','state'])
print (df.head(10))
        region                 state
0  New England           connecticut
1  New England                 maine
2  New England         massachusetts
3  New England         new hampshire
4  New England          rhode island
5  New England               vermont
6      Mideast              delaware
7      Mideast  district of columbia
8      Mideast              maryland
9      Mideast            new jersey
```

EDIT: loop solution:

```
out = []
for k, v in d.items():
    for x in v:
        out.append((k, x))
        
df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['region','state'])
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Could you convert the list comprehension into a for loop, so that I can better understand?

Comment: @tainangao- Sure, give me a sec